# Notación Matematica en Stackoverflow

Tags: discusión, formato

Hoy he visto que alguien ha escrito en notación Matemática un problema de programación en `r` y en el inicio de su pregunta escribe :

```
$$
    f(x)= 
    \left\{ 
      \begin{array}{lcc}
           0 &   si  & x < 0 \\
        \\ 2-2\cdot x &  si & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
        \\ 0 &  si  & x > 1
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $$
```

Para escribir, una función matemática por tramos:

[image: imagen]

Me pregunto si es que hay algún motivo especial por el cual no se puede escribir esta función tal cual como es concebida en matemáticas, esto en relación a que las matemáticas forman parte importante de la programación, sin ir mas lejos los Algoritmos ya existían antes de la computación y que duda cabe que son la semilla de toda la tecnología actual.

Y por otro lado en **StackExchange MATHEMATICS** el mismo código que publicó la persona, funciona y muestra la función tal cual como se escriben en los libros, de esta manera se lograrían preguntas y respuestas mas elegantes y evitando que se inserten imágenes.

Desde ya muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: no me queda claro que esperas o cual es la pregunta. pero luce interesante.

Comment: *escribir esta función tal cual como es concebida en matemáticas*, quieres que se incluya una herramienta como si fuese una calculadora texas instrument? esto deberías colocarlo en Meta de SE como feature request.

Comment: Me refiero a que si escribes por ejemplo un n elevado a x se pueda ver tal como es en matemáticas, o tal como se ve en el editor de la página que menciono, pero claro ellos son del tema especifico de matemáticas pero el editor es el mismo, por eso pensé que se podría escribir la expresión tal cual, pero como ya ves, no se puede.

Comment: Estás hablando de [LaTeX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), y no estoy seguro de lo que diré a continuación, pero me parece que [es.so] no tiene activa la característica (plugin, parser, o como sea que se implemente) para compilar código de LaTeX como lo hace [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Exacto.. no todos los sitios tienen todas las caracteristicas habilitadas.. por ejemplo el sitio de ajedrez tiene un tablero con movimientos, el de matematicas las formulas, los de peliculas extractos de youtube, el de juegos las cartas de magic... cada sitio tiene algunas cosas particulares activadas... Esto no esta activo aca, y yo por lo menos, no veo la necesidad ya que no somos un sitio de matematicas....

Comment: @gbianchi yo apoyo al op; en algunas circunstancia como el hecho de que se debe saber ingles mínimamente si te dedicas a la programación, pasa lo mismo con las matemáticas; algunos algoritmos pueden ser diseñados y optimizando en base a funciones matemáticas. que solo un pequeño puñados de desarrolladores lo usen puede ser cierto pero tambien es cierto que la mayoría de cosas manejadas en R lenguaje de programación son planteadas como funciones matemáticas y es en ese punto donde cobra sentido... pero no creo que aquí sea el lugar donde pedirlo...

Comment: En mi opinión, este tipo de notación sería muy útil, pero ciertamente no es la opinión oficial: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106281/mathjax-should-also-work-in-stackoverflow

Comment: en algunas respuestas he usado el charts de google apis x ej: `<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&amp;chl=d%3D%5Clfloor%20%5Clog_%7B10%7Dn%20%5Crfloor%20%2B%201%20" alt="formula">`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es un código escrito en Latex, que es utilizado para darle formato al texto.
Latex es bastante usado para escribir texto con formulas, por ejemplo para escribir artículos científicos en algunos casos automatizando los resultados cuando son obtenidos por ejemplo de un script en MATLAB, python o R.

Latex no corre por defecto en el navegador, para renderizar Latex en HTML debes ayudarte de un graficador (en `<canvas>`, `<svd>` o en `<img>`).

Acá en stackoverflow puedes utilizar una api que reciba el código Latex y como resultado te genere la imagen. La estructura de la petición es:

`https://latex.codecogs.com/{type}.{format}?{LaTeX-Markup}`

Por ejemplo:
[https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?\dpi{50}](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?%5Cdpi%7B50%7D)&space;\int_{x}^{y}xdx

genera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo debes agregar imagen pegando la url con el prefijo `https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?\dpi{50}&space;\`**+{tu sintáxis en Latex}**. Hay más opciones, ver: [Implement an API call to display LaTeX as inline image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/implement-an-api-call-to-display-latex-as-inline-image)

[image: ejemplo1]

Comment: solo para aclarara algo <canvas>, <svd> o en <img> son etiquetas html que son interpretadas por el navegador, estas etiquetas requieren una estructura de datos para ser renderizadas por el navegador en un dibujo vectorial... para que corrijas hay que Latex es quien provee los datos a la etiqueta... que si corre en el navegador...